# Appear animation of UIViewController called by pushViewController displayed twice

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have UISearchBar, and I want to display another UIViewController when I click Search button from UISearchBar. I am using the following method for that:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *add =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];
}
```

Problem is that the appear animation of the UIViewController is called twice. I see two times the slide of the old Controller from right side to left.

Now, if i use the same code to display new controller when clicked on some regular UIButton the animation issue is gone. So it seems it is somehow related with UISearchBar.

The delegate method of searchBarSearchButtonClicked is called only once.

The code to reproduce problem is very minimal, may be I will attach sample project bit later.

But the UIVIewCOntroller with Search bar looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"search a pub or a place", nil);
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:searchBar];

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    DLog(@"Filter searchBarSearchButtonClicked");
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *add =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];
}
```

Problem is both on iOS 8 and 9.

**Edit:**

I uploaded sample project [here](http://www.filedropper.com/searchbarproblem). It is very minimalistic.

**Edit2:**

If I present the controller like this, not through navigation controller, the animation is displayed only once. (It is another animation though - from bottom up, the previous was from right to left). But I need to do it via navigation controller. So the problem seems to be related to UISearchBar Search clicked + Navigation Controller.

```
[self presentViewController:add
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

Of course I can also call it without animation like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:NO];
```

But what if I want an animation.

**Edit3:**

I tried to display second controller via segue, but it didn't help.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seg1" sender:self];
}
```

**Edit4:**

I have reported this bug to Apple because I guess this must be bug in UIKit. Anyways, if someone will find workaround it would be good.

Comment: Maybe something is getting mixed up with the dismissal of a UISearchController.  One thing to try would be to move your button delegate code into a method with a simple signature, then call it with `self performSelector`.

Comment: thanks for the idea, i have tried it, but problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find anything in the docs that says a search bar as a navigation item `titleView` is prohibited, but that is the cause of the unwanted animation.

Add the button as a subview, and a single animation will occur on the push.  A quick fix is to remove it before proceeding with the presentation ...

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    [self.navigationItem.titleView removeFromSuperview];

    // and so on with the OP code...
```

Strangely, this fixes the extra animation problem, but doesn't actually remove the search bar.  Inspecting the titleView right after the removal shows the search bar is still there.

Comment: Great catch! So I dont know if I should rely on that hacky solution, since it looks also buggy (if it doesnt remove the view) - but it works, yes. Which button I could add as subview and where?

Comment: may be I could rely on that hacky solution, like if it works in moment of compile time, it will work forever regardless if apple will fix the removing in some future version or not. I am not sure. Depends if UIKit is linked against compiled app, or called dynamically.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  The way I'd handle this is to use the UISearchController as recommended in the docs.  The hack suggested here is to get around the original hack of the search bar as title view.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have good news! I have discovered the animation bug also happens if you "focus" the UINavigationBar and then click some regular UIButton to show new controller. (Which worked fine if UINavigationbar was not focused!) That means, problem is also related to focus ! That means, problem is solved also if you call this:     [self.navigationItem.titleView resignFirstResponder]; before displaying new controller. But your idea was helpful too.